# How to count quantity of duplicate data?

Tags: mysql

I want to count data with unique `ID` buat same as `pn`.This is my sample data:

```
id_form                  id_purchase               pn
PUR3-20190515022552     PUR-20190515022552  02N64073
PUR2-20190515022552     PUR-20190515022552  02N64073
PUR1-20190515022552     PUR-20190515022552  02N64073
```

This is my code :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM pur_supp WHERE pn = '02N64073' GROUP BY id_purchase
```

When I run the code, that total still 3 but I want that total is 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_purchase) as Total FROM pur_supp WHERE pn = '02N64073'
```

Comment: This code is so great. Can you tell me about distict funtion ?

Comment: DISTINCT means "Give me some unique data dear SQL" :)

Here is documentation 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp
or
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html